# How I do slow start with nginx and/or Apache?

Tags: php, apache, caching, nginx, iptables

I have a server where nginx serves as a front load balancer and Apache with mod_php as application server on backend.

During peak hours if I restart apache as is immediately after restart it will die under current load because no caches primed yet.

I was thinking may be there is a way to do a slow start somehow? I.e. throttling number of connections depending on service uptime or something, like "allow no more than 10 connections than 1 second before" or something like this.

more low-level approach with iptables will work for me too, just do not know where to look for it.

Comment: You should think about using nginx cache. Cashing with apache when you already have nginx isn't good idea before you absolutly know you need this working exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't rely on users warming the caches, I'd prefer to:

1/ Put Nginx into "Maintenance Mode" and have it temporarily proxy to a HTML file (fast)

2/ Warm the caches yourself using wget on the 8080 (or whatever) port (or preferably a cli PHP script if possible, but it isn't always)

3/ Once warmed exit maintenance mode.

P.s when I refer to maintenance mode, I'm not aware of a switch that nginx has to enable this, but you could use bash scripts to alter the config to flick it on/off.

Answer (score 0):

Do a reload but please don't restart Apache. You are lucky you have nginx to smooth the peak, and/or return an error page when Apache is down, but it doesn't allow you to play with the HTTP service the way you like. In an environment production, at least at my job, that'd get me fired.

I beleive nginx must have a config or a way to implement a script to wait ie 60 seconds since a node is detected online (active) before considering it as (available).